# Render activeadmin view in rspec view spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, activeadmin

I'm having issue with rendering an active admin view

```
RSpec.describe "active_admin/resource/new" do
  it "is just simple test" do
    render
 end    
end
```

but it returns

```
Failure/Error: 
   render# template: 'active_admin/resource/new.html.arb'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `renderer_for' for :Arbre::Context
     # ./spec/views/admin/form_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How to properly render it so I can do some tests on its content

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a starting point: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/spec/unit/views/pages/form_spec.rb